# jQuery - add classes to separate elements in order?

Tags: jquery, loops, dynamic, addclass

I have classes with different values in them and i want to add those classes to set elements in order.

This is supposed to be just an explanation of what im looking for:

```
<div class="These">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These">Lorem ipsum</div>

$('.These').each(function() {
    var TheseINDEX = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('first, second, third');
});
```

Result:

```
<div class="These first">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These second">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These third">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Not like that abomination above was perfect but theres another thing.. I'm also thinking that it would be cool if that would loop.

Lets say i have 3 classes just like before and those 3 classes would be added to 8 elements

Result would be this:

```
<div class="These first">Lorem ipsum</div> <!-- #1 -->
<div class="These second">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These third">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These first">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These second">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These third">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These first">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="These second">Lorem ipsum</div> <!-- #8 -->
```

as in it would keep adding these preset classes until theres no ".These" for them to be added to. This looping would work much like a backup incase you run out of classes...

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4PAZ/ -  jsfiddle of my example..

Any ideas?

Comment: Your first example will result in `class="These first, second, third"` on every `div`, not like you intended.

Comment: it was just explanitory code thats all

Comment: @Joonas there's a simpler answer to this that no-one else thought of (and is now in my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
$('.These').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).addClass(classes[i  % classes.length]);
});
```

or, more simply (and efficiently):

```
var classes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
$('.These').addClass(function(i, c) {
    return classes[i % classes.length];
});
```

In particular, this version requires only one function call per element, whereas the original required three (i.e. the callback, the `$(this)` constructor, and `addClass`).

Answer (score 5):

```
var classes=["first","second","third"];

$('.These').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(classes[i%classes.length]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4PAZ/1

Comment: Nice. You beat me to it by about 2 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

If you store the different CSS class names in an array, you can use modula arithmetic to get the one you want based on the index of the element. Also, the `each` function provides a parameter which is the index of that element so you don't need to recalculate it with `$(this).index();`

```
var arrCssClasses = ['first', 'second', 'third']; 

$('.These').each(function(idx) {
    //var TheseINDEX = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass(arrCssClasses[idx%arrCssClasses.length]);
});
```